# Render Audio element with Audio tag in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, audio

I'm making a little audio player and playlist with angularjs.

For now I been managing the src from the audio tag like this:

```
<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
    <source ng-src="{{mainAudioSrc}}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

And in the angularjs controller

```
$scope.setAudioSrc = function(audioSrc){
   $scope.mainAudioSrc = audioSrc;
   var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
   audio.load();
   audio.play();
};
```

This works fine. The I changed it to creating a new Audio element in the angularjs controller. I can also modify the src and play.

```
$scope.audio = new Audio();
...code...
$scope.audio.src = audioSrc; 
$scope.audio.load();
$scope.audio.play();
```

This also works, but with no interface of course.

**The question:**
How can I render the audio tag associated to the $scope.audio so that I don't have to make a js interface to play and pause the audio element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that getting the audio tag gets the audio element itself (and can access the volume or loop attribute for example), so I ended doing this:

```
$scope.audio = document.getElementById('audio')
$scope.audio.volume = 0.8;
$scope.audio.src = someUrlToAudioSrc;    
$scope.audio.load();
$scope.audio.play();
```

and the html:

```
<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
    <source type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Also this works (just the js idea without angular):

```
a = new Audio();
a.src = someSrc;
a.loop = false; 
a.controls = true; // <- The important thing, show element controls.
// Append element to document, for example
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(a)
```